# matplotlib not showing graphs in the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, math

i tried to plot a function that depends on other variables other than the main variable to see the difference and get the best resume but at the end the plot didn't show any graphs here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m


l=[(0,0.016699),(1,0.023958),(2,0.02724),(3,0.033468),(4,0.42456),(5,0.059325),(6,0.063399),(7,0.079788),(8,0.095916),(9,0.125),(10,0.14622),(11,0.20257),(12,0.21643),(13,0.28974),(14,0.4424),(15,0.55856),(16,0.59991),(17,0.72561),(18,0.9964),(19,1.6748),(20,1.69)]

for i in range (12000):
    t=i
    for j in l:
        a=j[0]
        c=j[1]
        v=m.sqrt((2*(150-(40*9.8*m.sin(m.radians(a)))))/(1.2*c*0.875))*m.tanh(m.sqrt(((150/40)-9.8*m.sin(m.radians(a)))*(1.2*c*0.875*0.0125))*t)
plt.plot(t,v)
plt.show()
```

and here's the output :
[image]

i changed the x and y so the x took the place of y and the same for y so the picture is before the changes but the same result and that's not the main problem, also i tried to change the '12000' to just 100 to make the compiling time faster but no result

Comment: try `plt.scatter(t,v)`  but you only have a single point as far as I can tell

Comment: `t=11999, v=4.237005569029153`. You have one point, and a line plot requires two or more points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are plotting only one dot :
record your produced data into a list and plot the list:

```
l=[(0,0.016699),(1,0.023958),(2,0.02724),(3,0.033468),(4,0.42456),(5,0.059325),(6,0.063399),(7,0.079788),(8,0.095916),(9,0.125),(10,0.14622),(11,0.20257),(12,0.21643),(13,0.28974),(14,0.4424),(15,0.55856),(16,0.59991),(17,0.72561),(18,0.9964),(19,1.6748),(20,1.69)]
data_t = []
data_v = []
for t in range (50):
    for j in l:
        a = j[0]
        c = j[1]
        v = m.sqrt((2*(150-(40*9.8*m.sin(m.radians(a)))))/(1.2*c*0.875))*m.tanh(m.sqrt(((150/40)-9.8*m.sin(m.radians(a)))*(1.2*c*0.875*0.0125))*t)
        data_t.append(t)
        data_v.append(v)
print(data_v)
plt.plot(data_t,data_v)
plt.show()
```

output :

[image]